# Can't Install VCLibs v140 x64

Tags: windows-10, installation, bundle

I am trying to install this package: `Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.27810.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx`

The installation keeps failing with this error message: `App installation failed with error message: error 0x80073D02: Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.0.32912.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. (0x80073d02)`

Interestingly the x86 version of the package managed to install successfully, but the x64 didn't. What can I do to get the package to install?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate version(s) of the Microsoft Windows SDKs installed on the system?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question.  Have you made sure `Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller` is not running?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure how I can check if I do have the Windows SDKs installed, but regarding ```Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller```, it doesn't look like I can disable it, otherwise I wouldn't be able to install this appx file. Any ideas?

Comment: Add/Remove Programs

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, I see App Installer, but is it safe to uninstall it? It seems I need it to be able to install appx files.

Comment: I didn’t ask you to uninstall it.  I asked if it was running

Comment: Yes it's solved now. There was a terminate button. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and it is funny how you need to close the desktop installer to use desktop installer.

What worked is running from PowerShell:

```
Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx
```

Comment: I was trying to install this package from the GUI and I was getting the error listed in the question.  This method worked perfectly!